# Issues with Albert hotkeys

Tags: linux, hotkeys, albert

Albert on some systems may have problems like this:

- Setting a hotkey gets refused
- A particular hotkey is not allowed
- Hotkey issues on niche system XYZ
- Can't set single modifier hotkeys
- The set hotkey does not work (Wayland)

What can one do about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Qt does not provide systemwide hotkeys and hotkeys on Linux are cumbersome for several reasons. Especially emerging Wayland delegates hotkeys registration to the compositor, i.e. Gnome, KDE, …. Interfacing theses is too much to handle and does not generalize well. Therefore the native hotkey will be dropped. The general solution to these issues is to let your desktop environment register the hotkey and run the command `albert toggle` or `albert show`. For the major desktops  you can achieve this by:

#### Gnome

1. Navigate to Settings → Keyboard.
2. Click <kbd>+</kbd> at the bottom.

See the [Gnome docs](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html.en)

#### KDE

1. Navigate to System Settings → Shortcuts and Gestures → Custom Shortcuts
2. Click <kbd>Edit</kbd> → <kbd>New</kbd> → <kbd>Global Shortcut</kbd> → <kbd>Command/URL</kbd>.

See the [KDE docs](https://userbase.kde.org/Tutorials/hotkeys)

#### Cinnamon / LinuxMint

1. Navigate to System Settings → Keyboard → Shortcuts → Custom Shortcuts
2. Click <kbd>Add custom shortcut</kbd>